# Rails ecommerce site with Spree what should be ideal blog solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, spree

I have e-commerce site using spree. What should be ideal blog solution please suggest. Since the blog has to be updated almost daily it should be like CMS with end customer able to do the same. Should I use spree-blogging-spree gem or maybe blog hosted separately on wordpress ? What would be little scalable and convenient for a zero tech customer?

Comment: Don't worry about scaling until you have to. Premature optimization is the death of all good things.

Answer (score 0):

By your own definition ("zero tech customer") I would avoid any solution involving coding or custom code. Blog is an area where dozens of very good solution exists "of the shelf", so I would go for a WordPress or equivalent. You could even get the hosting done for you.

Integration can be as simple as putting the blog on a subdomain, for example if your ecommerce is hosted at `pikachu-go.com`, you could have `blog.pikachu-go.com` to point to the WordPress instance.

This means that the blog & ecommerce are totally independant, which should be for the best. You'll have a bit of work to ensure visual consistency between both, but a good palette and a logo may be enough to start.

If for any reason you really need the blog to be part of the same codebase (against, I advice against that), you may want to have a look to blogs that can be added to your Rails application as [Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) such as https://buttercms.com/rails-blog-engine/ or https://github.com/kiddsoftware/rails_blog_engine.

Per the doc:

> Engines can be considered miniature applications that provide
>   functionality to their host applications

So this is a way to deploy it inside your Spree app without resorting to custom code.

Comment: This. Believe me when I say you do not want the call at 4AM "the blog isn't working"; use WordPress and don't host it yourself.

Comment: @JoshBrody @martin but the site must be seo friendly cant compromise on that. Having a subdomain as blog will affect seo significantly would need it to be url only like `pikachu-go.com/blog`

Comment: This is a trade off I can't do for you (and I'm no SEO expert). I would still avoid coding a blog like the plague. I'll add some info about alternatives

Comment: Update my answer with some "same code base" options